# homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> ***TRUE/FALSE TEST:***
>
> 1. There is a non-trivial group homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z.$

*My Attempt:*

> **True:** Choose $a,b\in S_3$ such that $|a|=3,|b|=2.$
>
> Then $S_3=\{1,a,a^2,b,ba,ba^2\}.$
>
> Define $f:S_3\to\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z:b^ia^j\mapsto j+3\mathbb Z$
>
> Then $f$ is a nontrivial homomorphism.

*Is the attempt correct?*

Comment: You must verify that the map you defined is indeed a homomorphism. In order to do so, you must first compute the multiplication table of $S_3$, and then calculate $f(xy)$ and $f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in S_3$ to see if they match. You will see that $f$ fails. The reason it fails, is that any transposition must be sent to $0$, yet the transpositions generated $S_3$.

Comment: It seems, you are just guessing. Hint: consider the kernel of any such homomorphism.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINTS:

1. The image of a homomorphism is a subgroup of co-domain. Does $\mathbb{Z}_3$ has any subgroups except $\{\bar{0}\}$ and itself?
2. Since $|S_3|=3!=6$ and $|\mathbb{Z}_3|=3$ then any function $\varphi: S_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ will be not one-to-one. So, the kernel must be non-trivial.
3. If $\varphi: S_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ is a homomorphism that doesn't send everything to $\bar{0} \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ then it must be surjective (According to what I said in 1). Now, what happens if you use the first isomorphism theorem? Note that $\operatorname{ker{\varphi}}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3$ but $S_3$ has no normal subgroups of order 2.

I have actually given you more information that you need, but to sum it up, there are no non-trivial homomorphisms from $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$. In a fancy way, they write this as $\operatorname{Hom}(S_3,\mathbb{Z}_3)=\{e\}$ where $e: S_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ is defined as $e(\sigma)=\bar{0}$ for any $\sigma \in S_3$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Observe that $(ba)(b)=a^2$. Apply your $f$ to both sides.

**Hint for the original problem:** The kernel of a homomorphism must be a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: p. 1 [https://www.math.okstate.edu/~mantini/4613info/ps04.pdf](https://www.math.okstate.edu/%7Emantini/4613info/ps04.pdf)

Proof: We must use the result of exercise 4.3.19 in this problem. Note that in $\mathrm{Z}_{3}=\{0,1,2\}$, the orders of the elements are $|0|=1$, $o(1)=o(2)=3$.\ In $S_{3}= \{(1),(12) ,(13) ,(23), (123), (132)\}$,the orders of the transpositions are each 2.

**Transpositions in $S_3$.**
For any transposition $\tau$, $o(f(\tau))$ must divide $o(\tau)=2$, and this says that $o(f(\tau))=1$, since 3 does not divide 2. Therefore $f(\tau)=0$, the identity, for any  transposition $\tau$.

**3-cycles in $S_3$.**
Note that $(123)=(13)(12)$. This says that $f(123)=f((13)(12))= f(13)+f(12)=0+0=0$.
Similarly, $f(132)=0$, so $f(g)=0$ for any $g\in S_{3}$, if$f$ : $S_{3}\rightarrow \mathrm{Z}_{3}$ is a homomorphism.

On the whole, there is only the trivial homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z_3}$: $f(g) = 0$.♥

Comment: Why are there backslashes everywhere?

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek Please don't make cosmetic edits to old questions or answers. That moves them to the top of the active question queue and wastes the time of people looking for genuinely new work.

Answer (score 0):

There is some special tric to find homomorphism from a group G to another group G'. At first we have to collect all normal sub-groups of the group G , which are precisely given by the kernel of the mapping f:G-->G/N , by f(g)=gN. Then by fundamental theorem of group homomorphism we will have G/kerf is isomorphic to f(G) . Now if f(G) is a subgroup of G' , then the no. of homomorphism will be
Aut. (f(G)) × n , where n is the total no. of subgroups in G' of type f(G).
Here , we know that, {e}, A3 and S3 are the normal sub-groups of S3.
So, first take {e}
Then S3/{e} is isomorphic to S3 , but S3 is not a subgroup of Z3 . Hence , there is no one -one homomorphism.
Now, take A3
Then S3/A3 is isomorphic to Z2 . But , Z2 is not a subgroup of Z3 . So, in this case we will not have homomorphism.
Finally, take S3
Then S3/S3 , is isomorphic to {e} , and this is a subgroup of Z3 , so from that we will have trivial homomorphism.
So, we conclude that there is no non-trivial homomorphism from S3 to Z3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Jose Carlos Santos .. okay .