# Nontrivial Homomorphism(s) from $\mathbb{Z_3}$ to $S_3$ - Fraleigh p. 134 13.37

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, intuition, cyclic-groups

Reference: http://users.humboldt.edu/pgoetz/Homework%20Solutions/Math%20343/hw`some number 1 to 17 that I forgot`solns.pdf

> There are exactly two nontrivial homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z_3}$ to $S_3$.
>   One is determined by $f([1]_3) = (1,2, 3)$; the other is determined by $g([1]_3) = (1, 3, 2)$.

(1.) How do you magically know there are 2 nontrivial homomorphisms?

(2.) How do you envisage and envision these? Where did they magically loom from?

(3.) What's the blueprint for the fastest way to check these homomorphisms? Do I actually have to pair up all the permutations?
I was thinking to start with $f([2]_3) = f([1]_3 + [1]_3) \\ = f([1]_3) \circ f([1]_3)$ and $f([0]_3) = f([1]_3 + [2]_3) \\ = f([1]_3) \circ f([2]_3)$.
How do you shirk multiplying $f([i]_3) \circ f([j]_3) $ for all $1 \le i, j \le 3$? Same for $g$.

The question for the other direction $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z_3}$. [homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/495195/53934).

Answer (score 4):

A homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z_3\to G$ is uniquely determined by the image $\phi([1]_3)$ of the standard generator of $\mathbb Z_3$. Also, $g\in G$ can serve as such image $\phi([1]_3)$ if and only if $g^3=1$.

Thus $g$ is either $1$ (which leads to the trivial homomorphism) or an element of order $3$. In other words, the number of nontrivial  homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_3\to G$ is the same as the number of elements of $G$ of order $3$. For $G=S_3$ these are precisely the elements $(1\,2\,3)$ and $(1\,3\,2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please flesh out if your $1$ means $0 =$ identity element of $\mathbb Z_3$ or $1 \mod 3$? Can you please flesh out $g∈G$ can serve as such image ... $g^3=1$ ? And where does the "in other words" spring from? Can you please notify me in your answer and not in a comment?